# How can i import and export data programatically in parse platform in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, import, export

I have a html file and related js file. I want to import and export data with js. So I have researched references but it said you can do this with UI. But I didn't find anything about how to do this programatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no endpoint in Parse Server for importing and exporting data. Some Parse Server hosting providers, like [Back4App](https://www.back4app.com), provide additional endpoints that you can use to import/export data programatically. Otherwise, the best way for you would be creating cloud code functions for importing/exporting the data and then call these functions. Here goes some examples.

For Importing, you can use this cloud code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("import", function (request, response) {
  var className = request.params.className;
  var rows = request.params.rows;

  var MyClass = Parse.Object.extend(className);

  var promises = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var myClassObject = new MyClass();

    for (var column in rows[i]) {
      myClassObject.set(column, rows[i][column]);
    }

    promises.push(myClassObject.save());
  }

  Parse.Promise
    .when(promises)
    .then(
      function () {
        response.success('Successfully imported ' + i + ' rows into ' + className + ' class');
      },
      function (error) {
        response.error('Import failed: ' + error);
      });
});
```

Then prepare a `data.json` file like this:

```
{
    "className": "ExampleClass",
    "rows": [
        { "ExampleColumnA": "row1columnA", "ExampleColumnB": "row1columnB" },
        { "ExampleColumnA": "row2columnA", "ExampleColumnB": "row2columnB"}
    ]
}
```

Then call the function like this:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR_APP_ID" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOUR_REST_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d @data.json \
https://your.server.url/functions/import
```

For exporting the data, use this cloud code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("export", function(request, response) {
  var ExportObject = Parse.Object.extend(request.params.exportClass);
  var query = new Parse.Query(ExportObject);
  query.find({ success: response.success, error: response.error });
});
```

And call this cloud code function like this:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR_APP_ID" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOUR_REST_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"exportClass": "MyClass"}' \
https://your.server.url/functions/export > out.json
```